# How can i change the Access Modifier of a Window from public to internal?

Tags: c#, wpf

How can i change the public access specifier to internal of window.

```
<Window x:Class="MyName.MyWindow" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
```

How to change access specifier from public to internal

```
internal partial class MyWindow : Window
```

{
........................
}

this statement show error ... have conflicting accessibility modifiers. 
How can i achieve this in WPF?

Comment: By using the [`x:ClassModifier="internal"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754029.aspx) directive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a XAML file internal in .Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647109/making-a-xaml-file-internal-in-net)

Comment: I found a duplicate instead.  Here's another: [Hide control within a WPF User Control Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717294/hide-control-within-a-wpf-user-control-library)

Answer (score 0):

Correct the both partial classes parts

You just have

```
internal partial class MyWindow : Window {
public class MyWindow {
```

Switch to

```
internal partial class MyWindow : Window {
internal class MyWindow {
```

Comment: Have XAML and source is attached to that, then?